# Format JSON with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, erp

I want to send an api request in this form:

```
         "line_items": [
        {

            "account_id": "1717893000000067010",
            "debit_or_credit": "debit",
            "amount": 400,
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000115007",
                    "tag_id": "1717893000000000333"
                },
                {
                    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000123007",
                    "tag_id": "1717893000000000335"
                },
                {
                    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000126003",
                    "tag_id": "1717893000000000337"
                }
            ]
```

The above JSON may have hundreds of (line_items) and each (tags) in it may have different number of dictionaries.

what I did in python is:

```
          accounts = []
          tags = []
          for line in payroll.line_ids:

            ######## code missing some correction for tags

            if len(line.x_zoho_jtag) == 0:
               the_tags = {"tag_id": " ", "tag_option_id": " "}
               tags.append(the_tags)


            for tag in line.x_zoho_jtag:
                for option in line.x_zoho_jtag_option:
                    if option.tag_ids == tag.tag_id:
                      the_tags = {"tag_id": tag.tag_id, "tag_option_id": option.option_tag_id}
                      tags.append(the_tags)

              ########

            if line.debit != 0.0:
               credit = {"amount": line.debit,"account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,"debit_or_credit": "debit", "tags": tags}
               accounts.append(credit)
               print(credit)
            else:
                debit = {"amount": line.credit, "account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,"debit_or_credit": "credit", "tags": tags}
                accounts.append(debit)
                print(debit)
          print(accounts)
```

As you can see in the above python code, I have 2 list (accounts and tags). I store (account_id, debit_or_credit, amount) in (accounts) list and it works fine.

```
  if line.debit != 0.0:
           credit = {"amount": line.debit,"account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,"debit_or_credit": "debit", "tags": tags}
           accounts.append(credit)
           print(credit)
        else:
            debit = {"amount": line.credit, "account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,"debit_or_credit": "credit", "tags": tags}
            accounts.append(debit)
            print(debit)
```

Along with that I have added (tags) key and (tags) list as you can see in the above line.

The problem that I am facing is in the (tags) key where I need to pass multiple block of dictionaries inside a list. So How to do that?

expected output:

```
  "line_items": [       
          {
"account_id": "1717893000000067010",
"debit_or_credit": "debit",
"amount": 400,
"tags": [
  {
    "tag_option_id": " ",
    "tag_id": " "
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000126003",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000337"
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000123007",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000335"
  }


   "line_items": [
       {
"account_id": "1717893000000067036",
"debit_or_credit": "credit",
 "amount": 400,
"tags": [
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000126003",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000337"
  }
```

wrong output:

```
            {
"account_id": "1717893000000067010",
"debit_or_credit": "debit",
"amount": 400,
"tags": [
  {
    "tag_option_id": " ",
    "tag_id": " "
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000126003",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000337"
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000123007",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000335"
  }


      {
"account_id": "1717893000000067036",
"debit_or_credit": "credit",
 "amount": 400,
"tags": [
  {
    "tag_option_id": " ",
    "tag_id": " "
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000126003",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000337"
  },
  {
    "tag_option_id": "1717893000000123007",
    "tag_id": "1717893000000000335"
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: The tags info  repeated for each tags in line_items where each one should be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when you are looping through the tags you are not differentiating between the ones that should go on the `credit` and the ones that should go on the `debit`.
What you need to do is get the line first and then get the associated tags for that line.
Below should work, I think, but has a bit of repetition so could be improved further.

```py
    accounts = []
    for line in payroll.line_ids:
        if line.debit != 0.0:
            credit = {
                "amount": line.debit,
                "account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,
                "debit_or_credit": "debit", 
                "tags": []
            }
            if len(line.x_zoho_jtag) == 0:
                credit["tags"].append({"tag_id": " ", "tag_option_id": " "})
            else:
                for tag in line.x_zoho_jtag:
                    for option in line.x_zoho_jtag_option:
                        if option.tag_ids == tag.tag_id:
                          credit["tags"].append({"tag_id": tag.tag_id, 
                                                 "tag_option_id": option.option_tag_id})
            accounts.append(credit)
            print(credit)
        else:
            debit = {
                "amount": line.credit, 
                "account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,
                "debit_or_credit": "credit", 
                "tags": []
            }
            if len(line.x_zoho_jtag) == 0:
                debit["tags"].append({"tag_id": " ", "tag_option_id": " "})
            else:
                for tag in line.x_zoho_jtag:
                    for option in line.x_zoho_jtag_option:
                        if option.tag_ids == tag.tag_id:
                          debit["tags"].append({"tag_id": tag.tag_id, 
                                                "tag_option_id": option.option_tag_id})

            accounts.append(debit)
            print(debit)
```

#### Refactored Further

Moving repetitive code block into a function

```py
accounts = []
for line in payroll.line_ids:
    if line.debit != 0.0:
        credit = create_account("credit", line)
        accounts.append(credit)
        print(credit)
    else:
        debit = create_account("debit", line)
        accounts.append(debit)
        print(debit)


def create_account(account_type, line):
    if account_type == "credit":
        amount = line.debit
        d_or_c = "debit"
    else: 
        amount = line.credit
        d_or_c = "credit"

    account = {
        "amount": amount,
        "account_id": line.x_zoho_account_no,
        "debit_or_credit": d_or_c, 
        "tags": []
    }
    if len(line.x_zoho_jtag) == 0:
        account["tags"].append({"tag_id": " ", "tag_option_id": " "})
    else:
        for tag in line.x_zoho_jtag:
            for option in line.x_zoho_jtag_option:
                if option.tag_ids == tag.tag_id:
                  account["tags"].append({"tag_id": tag.tag_id, 
                                         "tag_option_id": option.option_tag_id})
    return account
```

Comment: Thank you so much , It works fine now .. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess I see you... soo... move the tags = [] inside the top level for loop.

Comment: I dont think this answers the question asked, and it certainly doesnt make it easier to access either key or value.

Comment: sorry, my colleagues are shouting around me and I just went through the post quickly...

Comment: but I don't get it what is the problem, it seems to be fine. 
you create a 'tags' list what stores a dictionary in each item.

and this 'tags' list will be the value of the 'tags' key, right? this is not working?

Comment: I dont know. @Alqebaiti can you clarify the problem?

Comment: and what do you want? can you paste the current output and the one what you want to achieve?

Comment: This is not working right, (tags) list will store all (tag_option_id and tag_id) that in  (line_items) .. let us say we have 2 line_items and each one have 3 (tag_option_id and tag_id) . That code will store all of them. I used to add tags.clear() so for each for loop iteration it will clear previous data in it

Comment: try to clear the tags list before each iteration, that's all.
you declare this variable outside the for loop.

Comment: I have tried that with this line tags.clear() but  when i print(accounts) all others are reflected to the last values in the iteration

Comment: below this line  (for line in payroll.line_ids:)